# Cannot access 'user' before initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I am new in Mern development, and getting this "Cannot access 'user' before initialization" error in controller file

Controller/user.js

```
const user = require('../models/user')
exports.signup = (req,res)=>{
   console.log('req.body', req.body);
  const user = new user(req.body);
  user.save((err, user)=>{    
if(err){
    return res.status(400).json({
        err
    })
}
res.json({
    user
})
  })
}
```

Route/user.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const {signup} = require('../controllers/user');

router.post("/signup", signup);
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On line 1 you define a variable named `user`.

On line 4 you define a different variable *also* named `user` in a different scope.

At the other end of line 4 you try to call the value of that variable as a function, but it doesn't have a value yet. Hence the error message.

You **intended** to call the function in the variable from line 1, but since the one on line 4 [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) it, you are calling that instead.

Don't shadow your variables.

Change the name of one of them.